# MongoDB: Efficient schema design with embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm very new to NoSQL and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.  As an example I am trying to design a schema for a simple blog that has authors who have posts, which have comments.  Like so:

```
Author
name : String,
email : String,
posts : [Post]

Post
title : String,
body : String,
comments : [Comment]

Comment 
commenter : String,
comment : String
```

So this seems to be the most de-normalized way to design the schema.  It works great when I want to get a list of an authors posts, but I run into problems when I try to query a post by it's title.  This returns the author object and all that author's posts.  I can then search the posts for the one I want, but that seems inefficient.

What is the most efficient way to handle this kind of schema?  Should I only have a Posts object and make the author a field (or embedded doc) in the Post object?  Or perhaps it's best to store the data in multiple locations?

I've spent so many years trying to normalize relational databases that I can't seem to think in the NoSQL way.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Post
 title: String
 author: String
 comment: String
 posted: Date

Author
 name: String
 email: String
```

If the 'core' of your model here is the post then why not *make it so, Number One*. You can search posts by title, by author and by date.

Answer (score 0):

Denormalization does not mean foreign keys are forbidden.

I think you should definitely have a reference to your author by Id. However, and that is where denormalization comes in, you want to store the author name in the `Author` *and* in the `Post` objects. This way, you don't need to join the `Author` and `Post` collections.

```
Post
  title: string
  body: string
  authorName: string
  authorId: [id of author]
  comments: list of [Comment]
  created: date
  modified: date

Author
  name: string
  email: string

Comment
  subject: string
  body: string
  author: string (if you want anon comments)
```