# Mongo Collection in a Collection

Tags: mongodb, collections

I have a db schema which looks like the traditional Post, Comments schema s.t. Posts have many Comments.

There will be times where I need to search a lot of comments for a specific field and don't want the posts at all. So something like `db.posts.find({$where this.comments.field == blah})`, which returns the posts and not the comments, is not good.

What I'm currently doing is also no good. I have a field called comments in the Posts collection, which keeps the _ids of the Comments in Posts. This treats them too much like a relational database.

Instead, what I'd like to do is to keep a collection for each of Posts and Comments. Then, instead of embedding the Comments data into Posts and trying to keep that data in sync with the Comments collection data, I'd like to embed the Comment itself in Post. I am thinking of this as like having a sub-collection. Is this standard? What are the cons to doing this? Most discussions I see around this are geared towards embedding documents rather than embedding collections.

Answer (score 1):

> Instead, what I'd like to do is to keep a collection for each of Posts and Comments.

That makes sense

> I'd like to embed the Comment itself in Post.

This contradicts what you said before

> like having a sub-collection. Is this standard? [...] Most discussions I see [...] are geared towards embedding documents rather than embedding collections.

That's because "embedding collections" doesn't exist, and I'm not sure it would really make any sense (sounds like a materialized view to me)

From what you stated in your question, I think two separate collections make most sense (as they usually do for the prototypical example of posts and comments) - this has been discussed at great lengths ([an in short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195627/mongodb-efficient-schema-design-with-embedded-documents)). Then, to link them, use the good ol' relational way:

```
Post {  _id : ObjectId("..."), ... }
Comment { _id : ObjectId("..."), postId : ObjectId("..."), ... }
```

Comment: Ok, so this answers my question of what people mean when they say subdocuments as opposed to subcollections... Why don't subcollections exist? Why can't we do that? Then you get the best of both worlds when you really really really need just the Comments without the Posts.

Comment: Well, what's the difference of a 'subcollection' and a `db.comments.find()` and a `db.comments.find({"postId" : somePostId})`? Aren't those the features an 'embedded collection' would have?

Comment: A. Most of the time I need both, so having it be in one db pull would be good.  B. I'm using Meteor, so this would also decrease the number of subscriptions necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Having subdocuments in a document is nice if you don't have to treat subdocuments without parent document.

In your case if you won't do anything with comments it's better to embed comments to each post. In case if you want to find some latest comments or some comments of a specific user it's better to have two collections. Even if it seems relational to you.

Comment: When you say subdocument, to you mean subcollection? Why can't I have a sub-collection called Comments and then, when I need to reference Comments without Posts, I just ask for Comments?

Comment: Subdocument / subcollection `comments` is something like `{ _id, title, comments[{_id, text}, {_id, text} ...]}`

Comment: I find using `_id` in embedded arrays is highly irritating - `_id` is **not** a reserved name in embedded arrays - it's not a default (unique) key, not a primary key, and it can be modified. Also, arrays don't have collection semantics, they must be worked with very differently, so please don't contribute to the plethora of irritating misinformation that is already there. There are no 'subcollections'